# How polarization of photons affect amount of energy transferred while molecular resonance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

We know that force on a molecule due to a photon is by the electric fields of the photon and the force is electric force and is in the direction of force.so if the force vector makes an angle with axis of vibration of molecule then only a part of the force act on the molecule and then the increase in energy due to the force should be less than the increase in energy when the angle is 0.Does this affect vibrational transitions since energy transferred will be less than the required energy even if they are in resonance.Please tell me about your view on this topic.